# Prove, using open balls, that $\{x\mid\sum a_ix_i>b\}$ is open on $\Bbb R^n$

Tags: calculus, general-topology, multivariable-calculus

I'm stuck on one of my homework assignments and would very much appreciate any help. I have been trying to solve this problem for the last couple of days with almost no progression at all.

> Let $a_1, a_2,...,a_n, b\in \Bbb R$ and
> $$H= \left\{x \in \Bbb R^{n}\;\bigg|\;\sum_{i=0}^{d}a_ix_i > b\right\}.$$
> Prove, using open balls, that $H$ is a open set in $\Bbb R^d $.

My idea was taking two points $ x, s \in H$ and trying to bound the distance between them. After doing so I wanted to set $r$, which is the radius of $ B(x,r) $, to be smaller than the distance. By doing so we have shown that for some random $ x \in H$ there exists a radius $ r > 0 $ such that $B(x,r) \subset H $.
Unfortunately I'm unable to follow this idea.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9201), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: If $(x_i)=\mathbf{x}\in H$, say $\sum a_ix_i=b+\delta$ for $\delta>0$, then $\sum a_ix'_i>b$ whenever $|x_i-x'_i|<\eta_i$, where $\eta_i=\frac{|\delta|}{d\cdot |a_i|}$ if $a_i\ne 0$, and $\eta_i=1$ otherwise. Therefore $H$ contains a rectangle containing $(x_i)$, namely the $(x_i)_{|x_i-x'_i|<\eta_i,\ 1\le i\le d}$. Now can you construct a ball centered at $(x_i)$ contained in the rectangle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an expansion of my comment.

Select a point $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,\cdots,x_d)\in H$.
We may assume $\sum_{i=1}^d a_ix_i=b+\delta$ for $\delta>0$.
Then I first claim $H$ contains the rectangle
\begin{equation*}
\{ (x'_1,\cdots,x'_d):\     \mid x_i-x'_i \mid <\eta_i,\ 1\le i\le d\},
\end{equation*}
where $\eta_i=\frac{ \mid \delta \mid }{d\cdot  \mid a_i \mid }$ if $a_i\ne 0$, and $\eta_i=1$ if $a_i=0$. (Why we come up with such $\eta_i$? I have added an explanation to a usual trick in such construction at the end of the answer.)
To see this, assume  $(x'_1,\cdots,x'_d)$ satisfies the condition $  \mid x_i-x'_i \mid <\eta_i,\ 1\le i\le d$.
Then
\begin{align*}
& \mid \sum_{i=1}^d a_ix_i- \sum_{i=1}^d a_ix'_i   \mid \\
=& \mid \sum_{i=1}^d a_i(x_i-x'_i) \mid \\
\le& \sum_{i=1}^d  \mid a_i(x_i-x'_i) \mid \\
= &\sum_{i=1}^d  \mid a_i \mid \cdot \mid x_i-x'_i \mid \\
\le & \sum_{i=1}^d  \mid a_i \mid \eta_i\\
\le &\sum_{i=1}^d \frac{\delta}{d}\ \ \text{(Recall how we construct $\eta_i$)}\\
=&\delta.
\end{align*}
Therefore
\begin{equation*}
\delta> \mid \sum_{i=1}^d a_ix_i- \sum_{i=1}^d a_ix'_i \mid \ge \sum_{i=1}^d a_ix_i- \sum_{i=1}^d a_ix'_i=b+\delta-\sum_{i=1}^d a_ix'_i,
\end{equation*}
which implies $\sum_{i=1}^d a_ix'_i>b$, i.e. $(x'_1,\cdots,x'_d)\in H$.

We have showed $H$ contains a rectangle
\begin{equation*}
\{ (x'_1,\cdots,x'_d):\     \mid x_i-x'_i \mid <\eta_i,\ 1\le i\le d\},
\end{equation*}
centered at $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,\cdots,x_d)$. Does this imply $H$ contains a ball centered at $\mathbf{x}$? Yes, in fact, the open ball centered at $\mathbf{x}$   with radius $\min_{1\le j\le d}\eta_j$ is contained in the rectangle, and hence in $H$. (The fact has an obvious geometric interpretation when $d=2$. You may try to draw the diagram of the ball and the rectangle.) To see this, select a $(y_1,\cdots,y_d)$. If
\begin{equation*}
\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^d (x_i-y_i)^2}< (\min_{1\le j\le d}\eta_j)^2,
\end{equation*}
then for all $i$,
\begin{equation*}
 \mid x_i-y_i \mid \le \min_{1\le j\le d}\eta_j\le \eta_i ,
\end{equation*}
and is hence contained in the rectangle, and hence in $H$.

---

How did we select such $\eta_i$?
One trick is, we may want when $x_i$ is replaced by $x_i'$ in $\sum_{i=1}^d a_ix_i$,
the error "contributrd" by each $x_i\leftarrow x_i'$ is less than $\frac{\delta}{d}$.
Hence we constructed the $\eta_i $ by $\frac{ \mid \delta \mid }{d\cdot  \mid a_i \mid }$ when $a_i\ne 0$.
If $a_i=0$, then $x_i$ in fact does not appear in $\sum_{i=1}^d a_ix_i$,
and the corresponding $\eta_i$ can be any positive number you like.

Comment: may I ask how did you come up with the idea of "looking" for a rectangle contained in H? I might just be over thinking this, but i just don't seem to understand the motivation that led you there. thanks for great solution.

Comment: @userא0 In fact, when proving a set in $\mathbb{R}^d$ is open, it is more common to construct a rectangle than a circle. In this problem the equation is linear, and this also leads us to consider rectangle rather than circle.

Answer (score 1):

One approach involves a geometric interpretation of the set $H$. Examining the equation
\begin{equation}\label{eq1}
a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 + \cdots + a_nx_n = b,
\end{equation}
with $a_1, \dots, a_n, b \in \mathbb{R}$, it becomes evident that the collection of points satisfying it forms a vector space within $\mathbb{R}^n$ commonly referred to as a hyperplane. From this perspective, it becomes apparent that a point $P$ not satisfying the above equation can be projected onto this hyperplane, resulting in a point $Q$. In this context, one can examine an open ball centered at $P$ with a radius equal to the distance between $P$ and its projection $Q$.